# Windows 8 MinGW неправильный вывод программы

Tags: c, gcc, cmd, windows-8, mingw

При использовании следующего кода:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main ( int argc, char *argv[] ) {

    FILE *blabla = fopen("blabla.txt","w");
    if (blabla == NULL){
        printf("aaaa\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (fclose(blabla) == EOF){
        printf("bbbb\n");
        exit(1);
    }



    FILE *in_file = fopen ( "log.txt", "r" );

    printf("some phrase\n");

    fclose ( in_file );

    return 0;
}
```

программа начинает вести себя неправильно после примерно 40-го вызова:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно выше, программа делает дубликаты приглашений командной строки. Иногда вместо дубликатов приглашений появляются непонятные буквы и цифры. Иногда дубликаты видны уже после второго-третьего запуска. fopen и fclose всегда отрабатывают без ошибок.

Но если закоментировать инструкции первого файлового дескриптора:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main ( int argc, char *argv[] ) {

    //FILE *blabla = fopen("blabla.txt","w");
    //if (blabla == NULL){
    //  printf("aaaa\n");
    //  exit(1);
    //}
    //if (fclose(blabla) == EOF){
    //  printf("bbbb\n");
    //  exit(1);
    //}



    FILE *in_file = fopen ( "log.txt", "r" );

    printf("some phrase\n");

    fclose ( in_file );

    return 0;
}
```

проблема не наблюдается. Я использую MinGW GCC версии 4.8.1 на Windows 8. Программа собиралась командой:

```
gcc -std=gnu11 -o main2 main2.c
```

Спасибо за вашу поддержку.

Comment: Это мой первый вопрос. Я прошу меня извинить

Comment: `in_file` тоже бы на `NULL` надо проверять перед `fclose`.

Comment: Второй файл проблем не вызывает. Проблема сидит явно в первом файле.

Comment: Проблема может проявляться только в комплексе, а источником её может быть именно `in_file`. Добавьте проверку `in_file` на `NULL` и проверьте код ёщё раз. "some phrase" вполне может не успевать выводиться из-за буферизации, хотя код `printf` уже выполнен.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если прокрутить полосу прокрутки вверх, затем снова вниз, то все дубликаты исчезают (затираются). Я думаю, здесь имеет место ошибка Windows 8, но это всего лишь предположение. У меня нет возможности проверить на более ранних версиях Windows.

Вопрос можно считать закрытым. Всем спасибо за участие.

Comment: Добавьте вывод любого сообщения в начале программы (чтобы понимать, что она запустилась) и перенаправьте вывод в файл. Если после сообщения о запуске всегда будет "some phrase", значит проблема именно с консолью windows.

Comment: @insolor. "Добавьте вывод любого сообщения в начале программы (чтобы понимать, что она запустилась) и перенаправьте вывод в файл". Не понятно, перенаправлять нужно вывод всей программы, или только первого сообщения. "Если после сообщения о запуске всегда будет "some phrase"...". Не понятно, какое сообщение о запуске, если мы перенаправляем их в файл. Никак не могу уловить мысль, которую вы хотите до меня донести.

Comment: если у вас программа запускается через bat-скрипт, то просто перенаправьте его вывод в файл через `>`. Добавить вывод "чего-нибудь" в начало я предлагал сделать, чтобы понимать, что програма запустилась. Если запускаете через bat скрипт, то тут достаточно не отключать echo вывод.

Comment: @insolor, теперь понятно, что имелось в виду, но сегодня, как ни странно, я эту ошибку не смог повторить. система вдруг начала упорно работать хорошо. как только эта ошибка снова даст о себе знать, я сделаю bat-файл и сделаю перенаправление. возможно одна из программ, которыми я пользуюсь, лезет в адресное пространство cmd и портит его, возможно ещё что-нибудь. можно думать что угодно.

Comment: иногда бывает, одна из моих программ выводит в консоль 11 строк, а я сижу и думаю: "почему их 11? должно быть 10". потом чуть прокручу консоль вверх, затем вниз и вижу свои 10 строк. в результате время потрачено зря на то, что искал ошибку которой нет.

Answer (score 0):

У вас нет проверки того, что `fopen("blabla.txt","w")` не вернула `NULL`.

Если это происходит, то `NULL` предается в `fclose`.
Это приводит к неопределенному поведению, и программа скорей всего падает.

Comment: Не факт. При флаге "w" файл создается, если не существует. А, вот, второй fclose может вернуть NULL.

Comment: Пробовал делать проверку на NULL. не помогло. fopen возвращает рабочий дескриптор. Дубликаты появляются, как правило, после фразы "some phrase\n"

Comment: @DP0, Вы оба дескриптора проверяете?

Comment: Ошибка ведь может возникнуть как на этапе fopen, так и на этапе fclose, разве нет

Comment: Кстати, у меня эта ошибка не проявилась вообще